# EntityFramework Core Relationship mapping issue

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-core

I'm getting an error when trying to map a many to many relationships on Entity Framework Core, my Many-to-Many class need to have an additional field.

Here are the entities:

```
public class RelatedProfession
{                
    public int ProfessionId { get; set; }
    public virtual Profession Profession { get; set; }        
    public int SimilarProfessionId { get; set; }
    public virtual Profession SimilarProfession { get; set; }
    public double Similarity { get; set; }
}
public class Profession
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public List<RelatedProfession> RelatedWith { get; set; }
    public List<RelatedProfession> SimilarWith { get; set; }
}
```

And my fluentApi mapping:

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<RelatedProfession>()
            .HasKey(p => new { p.ProfessionId, p.SimilarProfessionId });

        modelBuilder.Entity<RelatedProfession>()
            .HasOne(p => p.SimilarProfession)
            .WithMany(p => p.SimilarWith)
            .HasForeignKey(p=> p.SimilarProfessionId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);


        modelBuilder.Entity<RelatedProfession>()
            .HasOne(p => p.Profession)
            .WithMany(p => p.RelatedWith)
            .HasForeignKey(p => p.ProfessionId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Profession>()
            .HasMany(p => p.RelatedWith)
            .WithOne(p => p.Profession)
            .HasForeignKey(p=> p.ProfessionId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Profession>()
            .HasMany(p => p.SimilarWith)
            .WithOne(p => p.SimilarProfession)
            .HasForeignKey(p => p.SimilarProfessionId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
```

When I try to run

```
dotnet ef migrations add xxxxx
```

and

```
dotnet ef database update
```

I receive the following message error:

> Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint
>   'FK_RelatedProfessions_Professions_SimilarProfessionId' on table
>   'RelatedProfessions' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths.
>   Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other
>   FOREIGN KEY constraints. Could not create constraint or index. See
>   previous errors.

Comment: Are you sure this reproduces it?  All those .Restrict options make it look like it ought to work. I'm also skeptical that the double relation (Profession  and SimilarProfession) is elementary. Consider writing  a [mcve] with simple Foo and Bar classes, only add a double link when necessary.

Comment: Also provide the Fx Core and Ef Core versions, list all relevant packages, specify the Db provider, ...